# Issues Connecting to HPC Head Node from Non-Domain-Joined Machines - Help Needed!

Tags: windows-server-2016, hpc

Hello fellow ServerFaultee's

I'm encountering a challenge with my HPC cluster setup. My main hurdle is connecting to the HPC head node from computers that are not domain-joined, specifically when using local user accounts.

Setup Details:

- Server: Windows Server with HPC 2019 installed.
- All cluster nodes are domain-joined.
- While domain-joined computers can connect seamlessly, those that aren't domain-joined present issues.

Presently, the HPC cluster restricts access primarily to domain users. However, I'm aiming to provide access for local users on non-domain-joined computers.

I've made adjustments to firewall settings, and reviewed network configurations, but the problem continues.

Has anyone faced such an issue, especially with HPC 2019, or can provide insights into a solution? Your assistance would be invaluable!

Many thanks in advance!